# Combine $(document).ready with a .change query

Tags: jquery

I have two queries

```
$("#repositories").change(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var src = "/images/logos/" + value + ".png";
        $("#img-product-logo").attr("src", src);
        getRepositoryBranches(value);
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        var value = $("#repositories").val();
        var src = "/images/logos/" + value + ".png";
        $("#img-product-logo").attr("src", src);
        getRepositoryBranches(value);
});
```

What i would like to do is combine both of the jqueries to work both when the site loads and when the repositories change.

What i tried up to now and doesn't work as planned is:

```
$("#repositories").change(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var value = $("#repositories").val();
            var src = "/images/logos/" + value + ".png";
            $("#img-product-logo").attr("src", src);
            getRepositoryBranches(value);
        })
});
```

and

```
$(document , "#repositories").on("load change", function () {
            var value = $("#repositories").val();
            var src = "/images/logos/" + value + ".png";
            $("#img-product-logo").attr("src", src);
            getRepositoryBranches(value);
});
```

i tried searching online for a solution or some help but i had no luck.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can assign your `change` event to the `#repositories` element as normal, and then `trigger()` it when the page loads:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#repositories").change(function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var src = "/images/logos/" + value + ".png";
    $("#img-product-logo").attr("src", src);
    getRepositoryBranches(value);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the solution!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you must've thought of this but why not create a function and call it as required?

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    CallOnChange();
});
$("#repositories").change(function () {
    CallOnChange();
});
function CallOnChange()
{
    var value = $("#repositories").val();
    var src = "/images/logos/" + value + ".png";
    $("#img-product-logo").attr("src", src);
    getRepositoryBranches(value);
}
```

If I'm missing something, or misunderstood your query, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. we generally avoid using functions unless is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Ahh got it. Selected answer is more optimized, compact and definitely more efficient!